How can I increase attic ventilation when ridge vents aren't enough
I am getting a new roof installed next week. Currently my house has ridge vents with perforated soffits. The problem I have is with the design of my roof, there isn't much of a ridge, so I dont believe there is enough ventilation. I wanted to add an attic fan, but I know that can cause issues with the ridge vents. What is the best way for me to increase ventilation?



Pictures would help to know what you've got currently.

Can the whole attic vent from the ridge vent or is some blocked?

What issues are caused by having an attic fan along with a ridge vent? We have a solar attic fan with built-in thermostat and the last roofing job added a ridge vent. No obvious problems, but such things are not often obvious, I surmise.

You don't "believe" you have enough ventilation - have you done the calculations to determine how much ventilation you actually need? It's a pretty simple calculation, and it's considerably less than you'd expect. I was shocked at how little is recommended...

Attic temperature readings are better than calculations anyway. Stick a remote weather unit in there and see what happens. Maybe there's no problem.

What makes you think there's insufficient ventilation?

While figuring out how much ventilation you need is a fairly simple calculation, determining how to achieve that is not so straight forward, particularly with passive (soffit + ridge vent) systems.  The problem is coming up with a value for the "free space" of the soffits & the ridge.  Most attics are under-ventilated because the soffit vents do not provide enough air flow.

I just added some photos. My concern is the roof over the main part of the house only has a short ridge vent. The 2nd photo is the soffit that is around the entire home. I haven't done the calculations but it just doesn't look like enough ridge vent. Do you think its enough? If not, would it be best to just add an attic fan? Should i cover the existing ridge vent when adding the fan and leave the ridge vent over the smaller roof section in the front of the house?


Functional, not just decorative cupola(s)

 image source no endorsement implied

Tubine vent(s)

 image source no endorsement implied

Scoop vent(s) (may have other names)

 image source no endorsement implied

Solar or non-solar forced fan vents

 Image source no endorsement implied

After a few years, you find out how many neighbours have shotguns with turbine vents, unless you do it first.
